# NDSolve: methods and step size choosing

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I am looking into [the documentation of `NDSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html); more precisely **how this function chooses the `StepSize` and how it chooses which method to use**.

---

## Regarding `StepSize` control, it reads

> NDSolve adapts its step size so that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal.

**Question:** How? Does it use an adaptive step size similar [to this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_stepsize) for instance?

---

## Regarding method choice, it reads

> `NDSolve` typically solves differential equations by going through several different stages depending on the type of equations. With `Method->{s1->m1, s2->m2, ...}` stage  is handled by method . The actual stages used and their order are determined by `NDSolve`, based on the problem to solve.

and also

> Possible explicit time integration settings for the `Method` option include: [Adams, BDF, etc]

with various submethods and options. A good tutorial about method choice and stiffness detection is [found here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html).

**Questions:**

1. What is the default method choice in `NDSolve`? (I am guessing it will start by `ExplicitRungeKutta`, seeing as it is the most robust from what I've been reading, but then which?)
2. Regarding stiffness detection and method choice upon stiffness finding, I [found this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html) that refers "Explicit modified midpoint, double-harmonic sequence, linearly implicit Euler, and sub-harmonic sequence" as possible methods. In that same page, I found how those methods seem to compute stability of the model, and use it to determine whether it should use a stiff/non-stiff method. Yet, what is again the default order of choice for those methods?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: As noted [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#26930), `NDSolve[]` uses a multistep method by default (LSODA) for ODEs; it uses Adams methods for nonstiff equations, and Gear methods for stiff equations. Of course, all the methods have different procedures for choosing stepsize; you might want to look at the books of Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner for more details on the methods implemented in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Have you had a look at the complete tutorial [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html)? I believe your questions are being answered there albeit it may take some reading time.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. and gwr, I'll give a look into your links

Comment: @gwr: +1 for that comment, but then -- do you know someone who did read the **complete** tutorial (and of course the updates for every version)? :-)

Comment: @Albert: Certainly not. But how many people will have read through the books by Hairer et al. - of which I spot at least three? ;-)

Comment: @gwr: really? I thought it was a necessary requirement to know these by heart before you even dare to type `NDSolve`....

Comment: @AlbertRetey and gwr - you doomed me! (Then again, I have been learning a lot from the tutorials. And I also got Hairer's book, seems really nice)

Comment: @gwr, for what it's worth, I've been reading Hairer et al.'s books way before `NDSolve[]` was completely revamped in version 5... \*whistles\*

Comment: @0x4A4D, could you tel lme where you found the info in your first comment? I was thinking I would find it here (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html#154961554) but couldn't.

Also, seeing as the answers to my questions are not simple and would hardly fit in one answer, could someone please post the main links and tutorials found in these comments as answer? Thanks

Comment: There's a link in my first comment, re: LSODA. The stepsizes taken by most of the methods supported by *Mathematica* are, as I said, detailed in the "advanced" documentation, as well as the HNW books; did you already look at them?

Comment: @0x4A4D ops,sorry, missed it now. Yes, I have been reading from several sources: mostly HNW's book, "Numerical Recipes in C" and wikipedia for the mathematical part (though HNW's is by far the most complete and will take me quite a while to understand everything I need). As for the huge `NDSolve[]` tutorial, I read some parts of it and got a faint idea on how it is implemented (I really loved the splitting features hehe)