# inspecting step size and order of $\tt NDSolve$

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to collect information about what step sizes and what orders is using `NDSolve` internally. I tried wrapping it into a `Trace` but it dumping a huge amount of non-relevant info.

Any idea how to retrieve this easily?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26072/ndsolve-methods-and-step-size-choosing

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected

Comment: The `NDSolveUtilities` package features `StepDataPlot[]`, which essentially does what is done in the given solutions, except that it uses `ListLogPlot[]` instead of `ListPlot[]`, and that the abscissa is scaled over the range of integration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of ways for each question.

The steps may be obtained from the solution itself.

```
ysol = First@
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];

steps = y["Coordinates"] /. ysol // First // Differences;
steps // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The use of `MethodMonitor` to extract method information is shown in [user21's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected/149#149) to [How to find out which method Mathematica selected?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected).  But while the example there,

```
Reap[sol = 
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    MethodMonitor :> (Sow[NDSolve`Self[[0]]];)];]
```

yields a lot of information about `"StiffnessSwitching"`, applying it to the `Automatic` method yields none,

```
Reap[sol = 
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
    MethodMonitor :> (Sow[NDSolve`Self[[0]]];)];]
(*  {Null, {}}  *)
```

One can use `Trace`.  Here is a slightly difference pattern to search for than the one given in [Simon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/150/4999) to the linked question.

```
Trace[
 NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}],
 NDSolve`InitializeMethod[meth_, data___] :> meth,
 TraceInternal -> True]
(*  {{{Automatic, NDSolve`LSODA}}}  *)
```

At first the method is initialized to `Automatic`, but when integration starts, it is set to LSODA.

Alternatively, one can use the tools for setting up analyzing `NDSolve` methods, which are described in the tutorials [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) and [NDSolve Method Plugin Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).

You can set up an ODE with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``, but the method won't be initialized yet:

```
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}];
state@"MethodData"["Forward"]
(*  None  *)
```

If you iterate (i.e., integrate over any time period), one can extract the method information.  (Beware it only gives the *current* information.)

```
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 30]
state@"MethodData"["Forward"] // Short
(state@"MethodData"["Forward"])["DifferenceOrder"]
(*
  NDSolve`LSODA[NDSolve`MethodData[<<1>>]]
  8
*)
```

We see that the difference order is 8.

So user21's use of `MethodMonitor` is useful when the method switches, but one of the other approaches above should be used when `MethodMonitor` doesn't return any information.  On the other hand,  to get the `"DifferenceOrder"`, I seem to have to get the method object from the `` NDSolve`StateData `` `state`; it's not clear to me whether that information may be obtained through `MethodMonitor`.

Answer (score 8):

I think for the order, it depends on the method used in `NDSolve`. But for the step size we can get easily from `StepMonitor` . For example:

We can get all the point where a step is taken in the solution process

```
data = Reap[NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]]][[2, 1]]
```

The step size can be plotted as

```
ListPlot[Differences[data][[All, 1]], AxesLabel -> {"step No.", "step size"}]
```

[image]