# How to get a method used by ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, implementation-details

How to get a method used by `ParametricNDSolve` for solving a problem? Specifically, a boundary value problem.

The code looks like that:

```
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{Eq1[phi] == 0, Cm[0] == 1 + b}, Cm, {phi, 0, 0.99}, {n, gs}];
```

I've tried tracing this line as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/150/70066), but the lines whichh look the closest to that answer are: `NDSolve'ProcessEquations'SeparateVariables` and `NDSolve'ProcessEquations'ParseVariablesDump'res`

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193858/finding-ndsolve-method-details), [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected)

Comment: Well, I've seen the second link already, but running `Trace` gave me an empty list. I'll look into the first link, thanks