# NDSolve and Explicit Runge-Kutta method

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Welcome all, I have a comment to explain how my system solver.   My response was to add

```
Method -> {"FixedStep", 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.125, MaxStep->Infinity]`
```

in `NDSolve`.

In the paper, the method is indicated as
a fourth-order Runge–Kutta was used by
choosing a unit of time in the form of 30 days in addition to 0.125 integration steps per 3 hours
But the Reviewer ignores my response. Actually, it is better to solve my system by the fixed-step method.
Hence, what is the problem in my response? and how to reply to the reviewer as well to get my paper accepted. Is there any simple specific fixed step of Runge-Kutta?

```
sy11 = {N1'[t] == 
        r N1[t] (1 - β1 N1[t]) - η N1[t] I1[t] - β2 N1[
           t] T[t], 
       T'[t] == α1 T[t] (1 - α2 T[t]) + α3 N1[t] T[
           t] - α4 T[t] I1[t], 
       I1'[t] == σ - δ I1[t] + (ρ N1[t] I1[t])/(
         m1 + N1[t]) - μ1 N1[t] I1[t] - μ2 T[t] I1[
           t] + (ρ2 T[t] I1[t])/(m2 + T[t])};
    co11 = {N1[0] == 1, T[0] == 1, I1[0] == 1.22};
    residuals1 = sy22 /. Equal -> Subtract;
    sol22 = NDSolve[{sy11, co11}, {N1, T, I1}, {t, 0, 30}, 
        Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
      StartingStepSize -> 0.125]
```

Comment: _Is there any simple specific fixed step of Runge-Kutta?_ I don't know a lot about it, but maybe `StepSizeRatioBounds->{1,1}` would keep the step fixed? There are a lot of missing details in your code, such as the definitions of all the constants and `sy22`. Without these nobody can run it to check if what you're doing is sensible.

Comment: you can remove `residuals1 = sy22 /. Equal -> Subtract` . and the constants are arbitrary. The code is run well. My question is how can answer the following question: please, explain the choice of ODE solver for your task. Was it fixed or variable stepsize? How you took into account the effects caused by the choice of numerical integration method?. all reviewers are asking me the same question.  @flinty

Comment: So why _did_ you choose ExplicitRungeKutta, rather than another method? By default `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` seems to have a variable step size - that's all I can say.

Comment: Actually, I don't known that before. I did a test to add `Method -> {"FixedStep", 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, StartingStepSize -> 0.125` in `NDSolve` and have tha same result and the code worked as well as same as  `ImplicitRungeKutta`.@flinty

Comment: Why do you ask essentially the same question once again?

Comment: The reviewer  Reject my response and asked me to explain how the system s solver by Mathematica? he ignored the stepsize and the method an Infinity of MaxSteps @xzczd

Comment: If the reviewer cares about such stuff, he'll reject of course, because `Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}` still leads to a blackbox. You should follow my advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193858/finding-ndsolve-method-details#comment504690_193858) to choose **classical** RK4.